# Iterative Solver Library in Fortran

Tags: fortran, linear-algebra

I wrote a code which solves large systems of PDEs using some discretization methods which basically involves solving large, sparse systems Ax=b many times at each time steps.

I currently use the PARDISO solver (from the intel MKL library) which is a direct LU factorization of A to solve the system. I would like to compare this method with the use of iterative solvers (which, with the use of preconditioners, might perform better since I could use the same preconditioner over many time steps if my Jacobian matrix does not vary too much).

My question is then, what library do you suggest for sparse iterative solvers in fortran ? I found one (SLATEC) which was written in 1993 so I wonder if there is something more performant which was written more recently ?

Thanks :)

Comment: Just beacuse its old doesn't mean it doesn't kick ass! :]

Comment: Some of this might be of interest: http://www-users.cs.umn.edu/~saad/software/

Comment: If you don't mind other languages, you should definitely check out [PETSc](http://www.mcs.anl.gov/petsc/). IMO, its precisely what you want.

Comment: PETSc supports C, C++ and Fortran.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would also add:
[LIS](http://homepages.ulb.ac.be/~ynotay/AGMG/)
[AGMG](http://homepages.ulb.ac.be/~ynotay/AGMG/)

Oh, well ... the [complete list of Linear Algebra Solvers](http://www.netlib.org/utk/people/JackDongarra/la-sw.html)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the comments, [PETSc](http://www.mcs.anl.gov/petsc/) seems to be exactly what I was looking for, just need to learn how to link C calls into fortran now :)

Comment: PETSc provides a proper Fortran API. You should check out the examples.